# How can I run my slim 3 controler action via cli?

Tags: php, command-line-interface, slim-3

I'm try to use https://github.com/pavlakis/slim-cli but I can't understand how to connect it.

I add `$app->add(new \pavlakis\cli\CliRequest());`
 in my Routes.php

and I want to run `\Controllers\Api\Token:getAction`
Could someone help me?

Comment: have a look on https://github.com/symfony/console ; what you are trying to do is overcomplicated and you will have to hack few things. Think about Symfony Commands as "controllers" but with Input and Output.

Comment: are you want add your custom controller in route ?